# how to direct internal users to a site http://blah

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, intranet

Hi is there a way in iis where http://wiki can point to a wiki website i have set up on one of our internal servers?

http://intranet points to our local intranet, so just wondering how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP host-headers and a DNS entry on your intranet DNS server is the only option I know of.

Comment: can you give more detail, for my site would i just need add a host header "wiki"? what/how would i need to enter on the intranet dns server?

Comment: CNAME or A record for DNS IIRC.